# How to pass string parameters from C to assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, parameter-passing, nasm

My group is trying to get string parameters from a *C* program and pass it to a routine written in assembly. We are using the *SASM* IDE with a *NASM* backend. How do we code it?

This is our *C* code:

```
 extern int valid(char * dna){

}

int main(){
int opt, error, temp;
char cDump;
char dna[41];

intro();
do{
    opt = menuList();
    scanf("%c", &cDump);
    system("cls");
    switch(opt){
        case 1:
            printf("\n\n\n\n");
            printf("                    ===================================");
            printf("\n                 Task to be performed: DNA Frequency Count");
            printf("\n                    ===================================");
            printf("\n\n                    Enter DNA string: ");
            scanf("%s", dna);

            error = valid(dna);
            printf("%d", error);
            if(error > 0){
                errors(error);
                break;
            }




            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 6:
            return 0;
    }
    getche();
    system("cls");
}while(opt != 6);

}
```

and this is our assembly code:

```
%include "io.inc"
extern _printf, _scanf, _puts, _system

section .data
length db 0

segment .text
global _valid
global CMAIN

CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    xor eax, eax
ret

_valid:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
lea ebx, [ebp+8]

again:
cmp byte [ebx], 0
je done
cmp byte [ebx], "A"
je next
cmp byte [ebx], "G"
je next
cmp byte [ebx], "T"
je next
cmp byte [ebx], "C"
je next
cmp byte [ebx], "."
je done

mov eax, 00000002
leave
ret

next:
inc byte [length]
inc ebx

cmp byte [length], 20
jle again

mov eax, 00000003h
leave
ret

done:
cmp byte [length], 0
je zeroinput
cmp byte [ebx], "."
je valid

mov eax, 00000001h
leave
ret

zeroinput:    
mov eax, 00000004h
leave
ret

valid:
mov eax, 00000000h
leave
ret
```

How do we pass the string parameter to the `valid` function?

Comment: Not clear. nasm etc are **assembler programs**, but you show _Assembly code_.

Comment: `extern int valid(char * dna){}` **defines** it as an empty function.  Write just a prototype (`;` instead of `{}`), so C will call the asm definition when you link them together.

Comment: As well _CMAIN_ will declare a second program entry point. If `main` in your _C_ code is the entry point then you won't need _CMAIN_ in the assembly code. CMAIN is defined in `io.inc`.

Comment: I can virtually guarantee that your C compiler will generate assembly code that is either equivalently optimal or even *more* optimal than the assembly code that you have manually written for the `valid` function. So the question is, why have you chosen to write it manually in assembly? That only makes sense if you're going to write something that is highly optimized in a non-trivial way that a compiler couldn't do. What you've done is very far from that.

Comment: @CodyGray our teacher wants us to make a code that the interface is made up of c codes and the one working inside is assembly codes... sorry for the confusion...